# Polymer 1.0 two-level nav drawer

Tags: polymer

Most "Material Design" sites feature a side nav drawer with two-level navigation in it using collapsible zippy menu items.  How would you implement this in Polymer 1.0?  Is there an element for this, or do I have to mix together a bunch of different elements?

Some sites that have this:

- [Material Design Spec](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)
- [Polymer Docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/)
- [Google Developer Site](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime)
- [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/)

I assume this would be built with a `<paper-drawer-panel>` with a `<paper-menu>` in it, plus the zippy behavior from `<iron-collapse>`.

What's the right way to nest a `<paper-menu>` inside another one?  I tried nesting them in a few different ways but the results have not been ideal.

Also, I'm surprised you have to write custom JavaScript to get collapsibles to work.  [The collapsibles in Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) let you link them together just with css selectors.

Comment: There's no current element for this but it is on their roadmap.

https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-elements/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question was asked, Polymer has implemented `<paper-submenu>`, to be used within its `<paper-menu>`.

For more information on how it works, see the Docs and Demo for [paper-menu](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-menu).

Here is a code sample from the Polymer site:

```
<paper-menu>
  <paper-submenu>
    <paper-item class="menu-trigger">Topics</paper-item>
    <paper-menu class="menu-content">
      <paper-item>Topic 1</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Topic 2</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Topic 3</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
  </paper-submenu>
  <paper-submenu>
    <paper-item class="menu-trigger">Faves</paper-item>
    <paper-menu class="menu-content">
      <paper-item>Fave 1</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Fave 2</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
  </paper-submenu>
  <paper-submenu disabled>
    <paper-item class="menu-trigger">Unavailable</paper-item>
    <paper-menu class="menu-content">
      <paper-item>Disabled 1</paper-item>
      <paper-item>Disabled 2</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
  </paper-submenu>
</paper-menu>
```